# Why Module['canvas'] is undefined after emcc?

Tags: opengl, canvas, webgl, emscripten

I have a simple C program that draws triangle using opengl. I tried to port it to JS using emscripten:

```
./emcc func.c
```

it generates a file `a.out.js` in the emscripten dir. I tried to run it from the terminal using

```
node a.out.js
```

but had an error `document is undefined`. So I created html with included `a.out.js`, ran in the Chrome and got an error `Can't execute addEventListener of undefined`. It was about `Module['canvas']` object. I took a look at the `a.out.js` and didn't find an assignment to `Module['canvas']`.

Now I got an answer, so I'll share it here for easier search.

Answer (score 0):

To use any graphics you should specify [that output will be html](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Tutorial#generating-html), not just js.

```
./emcc func.c -o func.html
```

Also, [this](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php?topic=33268.0) article could be helpful if you just started to use emscripten